# Running an instance of mongod from terminal ends with "[initandlisten] shutting down with code:100"

Tags: mongodb

I've been searching for an answer for a week now and haven't found out how to keep this from happening. I currently have mongo stored from my root directory into a file with path /data/db. The contents of this directory after typing ls...

[Contents of /data/db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYDBz.png)

After I run the command mongod I see this...

[After running mongod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Umv.png)

I've installed mongodb with homebrew and have followed the installation rules over and over after installing and uninstalling thinking I made a mistake. I'm stuck and am new to mongodb altogether. I've noticed that Homebrew is installed in /usr/local/ and I believe mongo is stored in /data/db/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some permission issue. Try changing the group and owner of the directory and the directory where socket file is being created through the command

> sudo chown mongo User:mongo User data/socket directory

Comment: I do not know where the socket file is created. How is this found out?

Comment: Search for pid file in your mongod.conf directory by default it is placed in /var/run/mongodb/

Comment: I appreciate these suggestions but I found a command that has allowed me to keep the daemon server running. I typed on the command line, mongod -- dbpath ~/Documents/NodeTutorial/ and this kept the server up. I do not know why this worked but if I type only, mongod, in the directory I desire it shuts down.